# Firebase Auth and Facebook login android - check if the user is a new user?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I am using `FirebaseAuth` in my android app and want to check if the user logged in is a new user. Is there an api method that exposes that information. For web apps this looks like an easy way as mentioned in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48982151/firebase-auth-check-if-new-user-on-facebook-login). Is there a similar method in the Android SDK ?

Comment: check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49435019/test-whether-this-is-the-first-time-the-facebook-login-was-called-with-firebase/49441000#49441000

Comment: works ... please reference to this as duplicate if possible.. thanks :)